# Locking Your Own NSPreferencePane?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is it possible to implement a locking effect in a NSPreferencePane that we create? Similar to the lock found in other system preferences panes (such as Energy Saver, etc)

I know that I could create a keychain item and then just have the enabled boolean of the controls bound to something that depends on the user authenticating successfully, but is there a better way? Something that presents the same keychain authentication dialog, with the same message, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first read the [Authorization Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html). Once you have understood the concepts, have a look at the [SFAuthorizationView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityInterfaceFramework/Classes/SFAuthorizationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for the lock icon. Note that although they are similar, a keychain dialog is not related to an authentication dialog.